# how to generate html output in sphinx-needs instead of needs.json

Tags: python-sphinx

i am trying to use/understand sphinx-needs.
As soon as i run the following command it is generating needs.json

> sphinx-build -b needs source build

But how to generate the html output from needs.json?
i don't want to have any custom layouts a default or predefined layouts (such as'complete') will do

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Instead of 'needs' you can simply use `html` in your given command.

Comment: yeah even that should work.@danwos.... edit: oh you are they guy who wrote this sphinx needs.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have generated my sphinx folders using the quickstart command

> $ sphinx-quickstart

you will have something that looks like this
[image: folder structure created by sphinx quick start]

After writing your needs in .rst format
the following command will generate the html files.

> $ make html

PS: You should not have any dependency problems.
Sphinx-needs need to be installed separately.